# Changing cube rotation of axis from center to right most corner of cube in opengl es

Tags: opengl-es

I am facing problems in rotation of cube , my requirements is rotate the cube so that its new position starts from end of one face , 
I tried to rotate the cube using opengl es command glrotatef ( 90,0,1) , here rotation happening at center of cube I want to shift the right corner of cube .
If I am not clear please let me know

Answer (score 2):

`rotatef` rotates around the origin. So you can either adjust your cube geometry so that its coordinates are arranged with the origin on the face you want to rotate around, or you can do it yourself at runtime with a quick call to `translatef`.

So, assuming your cube is 2 units in every direction (ie, extends one unit from the centre both positively and negatively), then where you probably have something like:

```
glRotatef(90, 0, 1, 0);
somehowDrawCube();
```

You'd put:

```
glRotatef(90, 0, 1, 0);
glTranslatef(-1, 0, 0); // to align the right face onto the local origin
somehowDrawCube();
```

Comment: Thank you for answer my question , one more additional question , does it possible to change pivot point of primitives in android opengl es

Comment: Nope, all rotations are around the centre. Normal practice is to shift the object so that the pivot point you rotate is the centre, do the rotation, then shift back so that the proper centre is the centre. Which, because of the way you apply things in OpenGL generally means `glTranslatef(-vector to pivot); glRotatef(as required); glTranslatef(vector to pivot);`